# How to get text of first HTML element

Tags: html, dom, traversal

How to traverse HTML DOM in order to get text of each and every element recursively. I need to get text of HTML element only without text of child elements.
Consider if nested HTML elements are there, then how to get the text of first element eliminating the nested child elements and respective texts.

I have tried "**elem.InnerHTML**", "**elem.InnerTEXT**", "**elem.TextContent**" but these all seems to returning text from all nested elements as well.

Code sample:
I have HTML as below:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD></HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV> SOMEDIVTEXT 
            <TABLE>
              <TBODY>
               <TR><TD>COLUMN1</TD></TR>
               <TR><TD>COLUMN2</TD></TR>
              </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I just need to extract **SOMEDIVTEXT** while current node pointer is at DIV without getting text of nested children.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so we can see what/how you do and what goes wrong

Comment: Off topic, but why is your `tbody` element outside of your `table` element?

Comment: The text you're trying to get at is stored in the DOM a separate node to the element inside the `div`, so extracting it on its own shouldn't be difficult. What have you tried so far to get it?

Comment: @Spudley This HTML is getting produced at client side and is not in our control. We can ignore TBody for now as it does not always come this way.

Comment: So, my basic need is to traverse complete HTML DOM. I am doing this through TreeWalker method as follows: var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT
    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so assuming (1) you're writing Javascript in the browser, and (2) you have the element as an object (you mentioned 'elem' in the question, so I guess you have?), then you can get the children of an element using `elem.childNodes()`.

This will give you a `Nodelist` object containing each node within the element. In the case of the HTML you quoted in the question, this will be two nodes; the first will be a text node containing the text `SOMEDIVTEXT`, and the second will be an element node containing the `<TABLE>` element.

So `elem.childNodes[0]` will get the text you are trying to extract.

But the DOM is pretty flexible, so there are other properties and methods that can also get the same effect, including 'elem.firstChild' as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) property. It gets text nodes.

For example:

```
document.body.firstElementChild.firstChild
```

It works for this code sample.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I tried this but I need to traverse HTML DOM and get innertext for all elements. Through your code, I will get TBODY object and not DIV. My problem is if my current node is DIV and I want to extract DIV innertext  (SOMEDIVTEXT) without getting child innertext.